# htaccess redirect if the url does not contain a specific character

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, tags

I'm moving the site to a subdomain and need certain tag strings to go to the subdomain and some to remain on the main site. Problem is both have a similar tag system.

I need this type of request 
https://www.site.co.uk/tags/example-tag 
to go here: 
https://sub.site.co.uk/tags/example-tag

but this type of request 
https://www.site.co.uk/tags/view?tags=14-some-varriable 
to remain unchanged and parsed to content without redirecting.

What would be the most recommended and best solution? 
I have written some code to work around other redirects but this one is causing me a headache.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

For your this mentioned example, below should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.site.co.uk/%1/%2 [R]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the code lacks precision.

Comment: The need is to 301 this type of streeng site.co.uk/tags/example-tag to a subdomain but  site.co.uk/tags/view?tags=14-some-varriable let through with no change. Other rules are in place and after having some time to play with this code you suggested I can understand a bit more but I'm still none the wiser how to make it work. 

PS: didn't know "enter" adds a comment to answer here hence 1st is a short one. Wanted a space....